# Android 2.2 Webview causes OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)

Tags: java, android, web-applications, opengl-es

First of all, thanks for reading this post and in advance for helping me with this matter.
I'm currently creating a webshell for android to run Webapps in, this is running on the Android 2.2 SDK.

The problem appears when i debug my application (this is done on an Android 4.0 Phone through usb):

```
09-28 11:32:32.415: D/dalvikvm(25629): Debugger has detached; object registry had 576 entries
09-28 11:32:36.355: W/ActivityThread(25764): Application com.android_api8_webshell is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
09-28 11:32:36.375: I/System.out(25764): Sending WAIT chunk
09-28 11:32:36.380: I/dalvikvm(25764): Debugger is active
09-28 11:32:36.575: I/System.out(25764): Debugger has connected
09-28 11:32:36.575: I/System.out(25764): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-28 11:32:36.775: I/System.out(25764): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-28 11:32:36.975: I/System.out(25764): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-28 11:32:37.175: I/System.out(25764): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-28 11:32:37.375: I/System.out(25764): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-28 11:32:37.575: I/System.out(25764): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-28 11:32:37.780: I/System.out(25764): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-28 11:32:37.980: I/System.out(25764): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-28 11:32:38.180: I/System.out(25764): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-28 11:32:38.385: I/System.out(25764): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-28 11:32:38.585: I/System.out(25764): debugger has settled (1497)
09-28 11:32:38.710: I/webclipboard(25764): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@41a184d8
09-28 11:32:38.765: V/StringUrl(25764): String: http://www.cidesign.nl
09-28 11:32:38.785: D/WML_SISO(25764): InitPasteboardJni
09-28 11:32:38.795: V/(25764): NotificationPresenterImpl::setSettingsValue 0 
09-28 11:32:38.795: V/(25764): NotificationPresenterImpl::setSettingsValue 0 
09-28 11:32:38.800: D/webkit(25764): Firewall not null
09-28 11:32:38.800: D/webkit(25764): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
09-28 11:32:38.930: D/CLIPBOARD(25764): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
09-28 11:32:42.440: I/GATE(25764): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
09-28 11:32:42.455: E/libEGL(25764): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
09-28 11:32:42.455: D/ShaderProgram(25764): couldn't load the vertex shader!
09-28 11:32:42.455: E/libEGL(25764): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
09-28 11:32:42.455: D/ShaderProgram(25764): couldn't load the vertex shader!
09-28 11:32:42.455: E/libEGL(25764): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
09-28 11:32:42.455: D/ShaderProgram(25764): couldn't load the vertex shader!
09-28 11:32:42.455: E/libEGL(25764): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
09-28 11:32:42.455: D/ShaderProgram(25764): couldn't load the vertex shader!
09-28 11:32:42.455: E/libEGL(25764): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
09-28 11:32:42.455: D/ShaderProgram(25764): couldn't load the vertex shader!
```

This is my code in my main class:

```
package com.android_api8_webshell;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;

public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        Log.v("StringUrl", "String: " + getResources().getText(R.string.url));

        myWebView.loadUrl(getResources().getText(R.string.url).toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }  
}
```

And last but not least, is the xml im running with:

```
<resources>
    <string name="title_activity_main">Main</string>
    <string name="url">http://www.cidesign.nl</string>
    <string name="app_name">Android_API8_WebShell</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

I'm aware of this configuration that helped others:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

This is however for SDK's above 2.3.3, the SDK i'm running with doesnt support this feature.

I really hope you can help me with this matter.

Thanks in advance,

David

Comment: If there is any way to use a newer SDK, you can always try setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

Comment: You can change to software layer using reflections so it will still work on older devices. I described how here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781655/android-setlayertype-webview/11145961#11145961

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to use the SDK 2.2 or could you use a more recent SDK (let's say 4.2.2) but supporting 2.2 devices through the support API ?

Comment: That's not an 2.2 SDK problem. Romain Guy answered on it already: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8825054/1761411

Answer (score 2):

To get `android:hardwareAccelerated` property and still support API 8 (2.2), set `targetSdkVersion` to 11 but leave `minSdkVersion` as it is:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...
```

When run on pre-API 11 devices, `hardwareAccelerated` will just be ignored.

Comment: i am running on 2.2 to 4.2 then any solution?

Comment: This right here. Does it not work for you? Just set targetSdkVersion to 17 - that's the one for 4.2