# Can reflection be used with methods that belong to greater than minimum sdk?

Tags: android, reflection

I am developing an app which has to support at minimum level 10 sdk. Today, I was coding when I came across a method `setLayerType()` which I need to use. But this method is introduced in **API level 11**. So, I used a workaround and used **Reflection** to use this method.

So, my question is, won't my application still crash on device which runs on API level 10?

This question came to my mind because, **even though I am using Reflection here, still, I am calling a method that was introduced in API level 11**. Will this method run successfully when I run my app on Android devices that run on API level 10 or will it crash?

[As stated in source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11145961/2389078), the method will run independent of OS level. But, **why should it run successfully on API level 10 device** which is still using `Android.jar` of API level 10 and that file doesn't even contain this method?

I tried to search it but couldn't find an explanation.

**P.S.** I wanted to test it on a device with API level 10, but as building full app will take some time, so it is not possible to test app on API level 10 device right now.

Comment: If the client only has API 10 (which is probably the biggest reason to use it) then you will get errors when you're trying to retrieve methods from API 11. I don't think you can assume people will have both available.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I am not assuming that people will have both, but I asked this because, app will be have a large user base and as represented by [usage statistics for android](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_content=buffer7a7fe&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer), 21% users still use `Gingerbread`, which is a number that can't be ignored

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, of course the app will crash if you call a method that is not present in its API level. This is true whether you call by reflection or not.

The point of reflection is that you choose whether or not to call it based on the API level. Compare `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT` to `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html` in your code and only proceed with the reflective call if the SDK number is high enough.

The point is that you isolate code with bytecode references to any method or constant or class that's not present in all API levels into a separate class that is only loaded by reflection.

Here's an example of some utility code I created just to manage this kind of thing; it loads one or the other implementation of an interface based on API level:

https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/common/PlatformSupportManager.java?spec=svn2361&r=2361

EDIT: @FD_'s answer works too which surprises me. Reflection is safer, but much more code. And it seems like the reflection approach is in fact unnecessary on recent, if not all, Android JVMs.

Comment: Thanks for explanation and clearance. I was in doubt over crash in app because, `That way the code will run independent of OS version.` is written in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11145961/2389078) answer, as I already told in question.

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need Reflection for that. Just specify your target sdk as high as possible, and your min sdk as low as it is now. Then, before calling a method that was introduced *after* the min version, just check which api version your app is running on:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    //Your code here
}
```

Trying to use methods that were introduced in a later api version will lead to a crash otherwise, whether you call it using Reflection or not.

Comment: That alone won't work. If the newer method is referenced in the byte code, even guarded by an `if` statement, it will fail to load since the class loader won't find the method it is referencing. It is a class load-time problem, not run-time.

Comment: Actually, it works. I just put together a test project and it did NOT crash.

Comment: Can you show the example? We may be talking about slightly different things. I'm saying that loading a class that references a non-existent method fails.

Comment: I cannot see why it didn't crash. Can you tell which device you tested it on, and what was your code that you tested?

Comment: Will upload it to my DropBox.

Comment: Here it is: https://db.tt/oVW2VoNx
I tried it on a Galaxy S2 running Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.4. Written and built using AIDE on the very same device.

Comment: Sorry, but you misunderstood question. Please check it again. I am aware of sdk check that you have done, but I was asking, what if you run your project without check and with just suppression of API error, on a device which has `gingerbread` OS. will it crash then, if not, then why?

Comment: @FD_ you are right! I verified that it does run. This confused me since I'm sure I've seen this fail before. The JVM can choose to load the class before first reference (like when referencing class loads), but doesn't necessarily do so. It's possible older Android JVMs had different behavior but clearly SDK 10 does not. Reflection might be safer, but, it's messy too.

Comment: Glad it worked for you as well. I did a second test, importing and referencing a whole class that was introduced in a later sdk version, and even that ran fine.

Comment: Yes it will work, but the functionality that we have provided view `API level 11` call won't work in `API level 10` device through this check.

Comment: No, of course not. How should it? The function is just not included in that system version.

Comment: Because of the Android fragmentation problems, declaring a too high SDK target level may ruin an otherwise perfectly clean from bugs application (not a typical hello-word, but a really complex application's code).